# Unable to return CPanel APIv2 json data using shell Curl

Tags: php, ruby, shell, curl, cpanel

I am trying to return data from CPanel's APIv2, in the case below.. I am trying to curl out the last 15 minute of logs from a client account, where the variables CUSTOMER_USER_NAME is a customer user name and DOMAIN_NAME_FOO.COM is the customer's domain name.

```
curl --insecure https://MASTERUSER:masterhash@MASTERIP_foo:2087/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_user=CUSTOMER_USER_NAME_FOO&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Stats&cpanel_jsonapi_func=lastapachehits&domain=DOMAIN_NAME_FOO.COM
```

When I run the Curl the JSON that comes back is:

```
{"cpanelresult":{"data":{"reason":"User parameter is invalid or was not supplied","result":"0"},"type":"text","error":"User parameter is invalid or was not supplied"}
```

Both that user and domain are CPanel accounts and in PHP this works -> file_get_contents on the admin interface however I am coding this daemon in another language and even shell STDOUT would suffice here.

Does anyone have any idea how I would accomplish this?  I figured I would capture stdout from curl for my Ruby daemon framework and go from there if there isn't a adequate ruby like way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer I was looking for that I solved myself in case anyone else has had trouble using ruby to manipulate the CPanel V2 API

```
require 'httparty' 
$user = 'v****l'    #master user account username
$apihash = '86W***********V'     #api hash
$url = '10.**4.1**.**9'   #sample ip address of server

class Cpanel
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://#{$url}:2086/json-api"

  def initialize(u, p)
    @auth = {:username => u, :password => p}
  end

  # mod = cPanel module
  # function = function, really!
  # args = function's arguments
  def api(mod, func, args={})
    query = { :cpanel_jsonapi_user => @auth[:username],
      :cpanel_jsonapi_module => mod,
      :cpanel_jsonapi_func => func,
      :cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion => 2,
    }

    options = {}
    query.merge!(args)
    options.merge!({ :query => query, :basic_auth => @auth })
    result = self.class.post('/cpanel', options)

    #result = result.to_hash['cpanelresult']['data']

    return result
  end
end

cpanel = Cpanel.new($user, $apihash)
puts cpanel.api('Stats', 'lastapachehits', { :domain => 'hu***********.org' })    #where hu**********.org is the account to acquire logs from
```

This can be repurposed for any of CPanelV2's APIs, just remember that 2087 is SSL and 2086 is encrypted.